# how to untar a file inplace in linux

Tags: linux, tar

I needed to move about 5 GB worth of files from one of my servers to the other, so I decided that tarring them up and sending the archive would be the fastest way.

However, the receiving server only has 1 GB of space left after receiving the tar archive.

Is there some way I can extract the tar 'in-place'? I don't need to keep the archive after it has been extracted, so I was wondering if it is possible to do this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has already been asked for many a times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tar/compress, ssh and untar in place. Not sure if that helps you. Good link about it here: https://superuser.com/questions/156673/in-place-extract-tar-archive